# Did the Jews move from Palestine to Germany?

Tags: nazi-germany, germany, jews, israel, palestine

I have an essay to write and the question is simple.

Did the Jews first live in Palestine and then move to Germany? If they did move to Germany, why did they and did they return?

I just need to know that. My searches on Google always yield me some long Balfour Declaration posts. Can I please have a simple answer?

Comment: I have posted an answer, and kept it simple. But why did you include the tag, "nazi germany", in your question?? This is a question about Ashkenazi origins, isn't it? What does the 20th century have to do with it?

Comment: A religion can spread geographically without any migration of human beings. And even when intermarriage is forbidden, it can happen. So I don't know if there is any way to tell whether an Ashkenazi Jew in Germany in 1850 was actually there because his/her ancestors, or some percentage of them, traveled from Palestine to Germany.

Comment: If there were a simple answer.... Whited's first law, "It's a little more complicated than that."  "The Jews" is not a monolith. Some Jews may have moved from Palestine to Germany. Others didn't. Still others moved from other places to Germany.  Are we talking only Ashkenazi?  What time period?  And why is Nazi germany in the tags>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Jews were largely [exiled from 'Judea' which Romans then renamed 'Palestina'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_diaspora) in 132CE by the Romans, after a rebellion against Roman rule. They dispersed into the Roman Empire, and gradually spread to all parts of the world. 1800 years later, there were quite a lot of them in Germany, but it's very unlikely that many, *if any*, had moved as individuals all the way from Judea to the territories outside the Roman Empire that are now Germany.

The [Zionist movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zionism), which started in the nineteenth century, wanted to return the Jews to their original homeland and create a new state of Israel. After the [Holocaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holocaust), this project became a much higher priority, and modern Israel was founded in 1948. Jews from all over the world have settled there. However, the previous inhabitants were [not happy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict) about this.

Comment: Of course it was not "Palestine" then, but Judea.

Comment: @jamesqf [That depends on who you ask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Mandate_for_Palestine_(legal_instrument)).

Comment: @HopelessN00b Maybe jamesqf meant in 132 CE where there was [a Roman province IUDAEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judea_(Roman_province)).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Could be, yeah.  Even so, I'm sure that a couple thousand years ago, not everyone called it what the Romans did, either... there's just not a handy Wikipedia link for what ancient Semitic nomad tribes called Judea/Palestine/whatever, like there is for the League of Nations declaration.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: Yes, that is what I meant.  It was Judea when the Jews were forced to leave by the Romans.

Comment: It should be noted that Judea is/was a single tribe of israelites that broke off and formed their own kingdom. So, the Jews want to restore Israel is a bit odd...of course, before that it was part of Canaan...

Comment: No one would be happy about getting kicked out of there homes.

Comment: Absolutely not. It was deliberate understatement for emphasis.

Comment: @jamesqf - It would be Judaea... *and* Samaria. And probably Idumaea and Galilea, and Edom, and Moab. But the whole region was know as the land of the Philistines - hence Palestina - before the Hebrews settled there.

Comment: @LuísHenrique, wasn't land of the Philistines 5 city states, roughly in what today is called Gaza? (Like in the map at http://www.crystalinks.com/philistia.html)

Comment: @tetra - perhaps it was a later innovation, but the whole region went by the name of "Palestine" in the 19th century - to the point that Jews living there were referred as "Palestinian Jews" (my grandmother used even to use "Palestino" as a synonym of "Jew". Even Zionists used to call it Palestine.

Comment: @tetra - a comprehensive explanation of the issue is here: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11866-palestine . According to it, the Old Testament uses the term exclusively for the region in the Southern litoral, but as early as Herodotus, "Palestine" was used to the whole polygon between the Mediterranean, the Jordan, the Negev, and Syria. So neither as old as "before the Hebrews settled there", nor as new as after the illegal occupation of Gaza and the West Bank.

Comment: @LuísHenrique, yes I (used to) know this. My question or comment was more related to "The land of the Philistines" than "Palestine". The original Philistines  disappeared from history about the same time as the whole of Judea was renamed Palestine by the Romans.

Answer (score 10):

It is not clear exactly when Jews first started settling in Germany, but there is evidence of Jewish settlement in the Rhineland communities of Speyer, Worms and Mainz already by the 10th century. There are different theories as to where they had come from.

The most widely held theory is that they were Palestinian. Most recently, this theory was challenged by Haym Soloveitchik. See his "The Third Yeshiva of Bavel" (in his *Collected Essays* Volume II) for a detailed description as to why he thinks that the community derived predominantly from Babylonia.

It's a technical piece, and for a more general overview, see [this](http://5tjt.com/interview-with-professor-haym-soloveitchik-by-rabbi-yair-hoffman/) interview with Prof. Soloveitchik. He makes reference to this theory of his towards the end. To the best of my knowledge, it is not well accepted: the theory of Palestinian origins remains the most widely held.

Comment: When you say `The most widely held theory is that they were Palestinian` do you mean that they migrated (more or less) directly from Palestine to Germany?

Comment: @SJuan76, yes. That they had moved to Germany from the land of Israel, rather than from Babylonia or Tunisia, etc. And that they had done so by the 10th century.

Comment: I thought the main theory was they migrated from Italy.

Comment: @Anixx, but where did they come from before they went to Italy?

Comment: @IanRingrose, the Italian Jewish community hailed from Palestine.

Answer (score 4):

According to Max I. Dimont's "Jews, God and History" (Simon & Schuster 1962), pp. 210-211:

> > After the conquest of Judah by Pompey, Jews and Romans became
> >     "inseparable." Behind the Roman armies carrying the Imperial Eagles
> >     marched the Jews carrying the banners of free enterprise.  The Jews
> >     were in Italy in the second century, B.C., in France in the first
> >     L> century, B.C., in Spain a hundred years later. At the end of third
> >     century, A.D., they had penetrated as far north as Cologne, Germany. 
> >     When the barbarians from the East invaded Western Europe, the Jews had
> >     been there for centuries.

Of course, not all Jews went to Europe.  Babylonia continued to be a hub of Jewish learning and culture, that it had been after the destruction of the First Temple, until the 11th century, A.D., corresponding with the violent invasion of the Islamic Empire.  See Dimont, p. 185; Iggeret Rav Sherira Gaon ("[The] Epistle of Rav Sherira Gaon").  Also, many Jews never left Palestine, although the Romans prevented the Jewish return to Jerusalem until after the death of Hadrian in 138 A.D.  Jews were again exiled from Jerusalem following the rise of the Byzantines in the third century AD. The Jewish presence in Palestine peaked in the 4th century, living in [43 Jewish communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_and_Judaism_in_the_Land_of_Israel).  By 638, A.D., when the Islamic Empire took control of Palestine, at least one study estimated that between 300,000 and 400,000 Jews lived in Palestine.  Jews also lived in Egypt, Turkey, Syria, Tunisia and Morocco after the collapse of the Second Temple in 70 A.D., until the establishment of the modern Israeli Jewish state.

You asked when and why Jews moved from Germany to Palestine.  Emigration of Jews from Europe began at the end of the 19th century, following the Dreyfus Affair in France and the rise of Zionism, increasing following the Balfour Declaration where the United Kingdom expressed support for the establishment of a Jewish state in Palestine.  Emigration from Europe to Palestine increased further with the rise of Nazism in Germany.  Dimont, p. 287.

Comment: Migration of Jews from Europe at the end of the 19th century actually began decades before the Dreyfus affair.